# Почему при создании файлов в папке, они создаются в домашней директории?

Tags: linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо использовать relative to home путь, но почему-то файлы создаються в домашней директории, а  не папке dir1000

Comment: Потому что вы через пробел перечислили 3 файла, точнее 1 каталог и 2 файла. Используйте фигурные скобки `~/путь/{fileA,fileB}`

Comment: @TotalPusher Действительно помогло, извиняюсь за тупняк

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса